# MouseListener and JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, mouselistener

I am using mouse listener to know when a user clicks on nodes of a JTree. Although when the user clicks on the arrow for expansion of a node(view childs) the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Core.ChannelView$1.mousePressed(ChannelView.java:120)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:263)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6370)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
```

ChannelView listener :

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                TreePath selPath = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
line 120>>>>>        System.out.println(selPath.getLastPathComponent());

                } else if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Double" +selPath.getLastPathComponent());
                }
            }
        };
        tree.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Any suggestions about how should I handle this case ? Should I simply try-catch inside the if statement? Also is this a good way to check for double-clicks or I should be doing it with a different method ? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your listener tries to get the node at the mouse location. If there isn't any node, null is returned by `tree.getPathForLocation()`. Just test if `selPath` is null before calling a method on it:

```
if (selPath == null) {
    System.out.println("No node at this location");
}
else {
    if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
    ...
}
```

And yes, [`getClickCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount%28%29) returns the number of clicks associated with the event, so it seems appropriate to check if it's a double or a simple click.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using mouse listener to know when a user clicks on nodes of a JTree.

Use a [`TreeSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#addTreeSelectionListener%28javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener%29) instead.  The [`TreeSelectionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionEvent.html) has some very handy [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionEvent.html#method_summary) for discovering which nodes were/are selected.

See [How to Use Trees - Responding to Node Selection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select) for more details.

Comment: I checked that listener and implemented it but I couldn't find how I could check for double click.Is that even possible?